# PHP: Uncompressing gzcompressed file with gzuncompress and fopen

Tags: php, zlib, gzip, compression

I am trying to uncompress a binary file and then uncompress it to test whether the compresssion is working. 
However the 'uncompressed' file  has the same data as the 'compressed' file. As though the uncompression never happened. I have listed code below.
thanks in advance:

```
//compressing  
//read file  
$filename = 'tocompress/tocompress'.$number_input.'.bin';  
$contents=fread($fp,filesize($filename));  
fclose($fp);  
//compress file  
$compressing = gzcompress($contents , '0');  
//write to file  
$fp = fopen('compressed/compressed'.$number_input.'.bin', 'wb');  
 fwrite($fp, $compressing);  
 fclose($fp);  

//uncompressing  
//read file  
$uncompfilename='compressed/compressed'.$number_input.'.bin';  
$fp=fopen($uncompfilename,'rb');  
$uncompresscontents=fread($fp,filesize($uncompfilename));  
fclose($fp);  
//uncompress file  
$uncompressing = gzuncompress($uncompresscontents);  
//write to file  
$fp = fopen('uncompressed/uncompressed'.$number_input.'.bin', 'wb');  
 fwrite($fp, $uncompresscontents);  
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gzcompress` takes an optional second argument which sets compression level, from 0-9. You're setting it to 0 (no compression) and you should be using an int, not a string:

You have `gzcompress($contents, '0');`

You want `gzcompress($contents, 9);`

From [php.net/gzcompress](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php):

> The level of compression. Can be given as 0 for no compression up to 9
>   for maximum compression.